# Maven + RoboGuice + ActionBarSherlock + RoboGuice-Sherlock

Tags: android, maven, actionbarsherlock, roboguice

I am trying to create an Android base project using android-quickstart archetype, and adding RoboGuice, ActionBarSherlock dependencies, plus RoboGuice-Sherlock to combine the two.

This is my pom.xml:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.myapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>BaseApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>
    <name>BaseApp</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <platform.version> 4.1.1.4
        </platform.version>
        <android.plugin.version>3.6.0</android.plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>${platform.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.roboguice</groupId>
            <artifactId>roboguice</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.actionbarsherlock</groupId>
            <artifactId>actionbarsherlock</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.0</version>
            <type>apklib</type>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.rtyley</groupId>
            <artifactId>roboguice-sherlock</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>



    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${android.plugin.version}</version>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>16</platform>
                    </sdk>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

But m2eclipse wont work with this Pom.xml, as it is unable to find the apklib dependency. 
Speficically I am getting the following message under "Problems" tab in Eclipse:

```
dependency=[com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:apklib:4.4.0:compile] not found in workspace    pom.xml /BaseApp    line 1  me.gladwell.eclipse.m2e.android.markers.dependency.apklib
```

I have tried removing the `<type>apklib</type>` line but then my ABS resources (namely the required Themes) are not imported into the project.

I've read in [several questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8831481/apklib-does-not-get-installed-in-maven-repo?lq=1) that the apklib type only works on command line, and that if I want to stick to the IDE I need to import ABS manually as a library. I did, but then RoboGuice crashes because the project becomes a library project and, apparently, resource ids are not final anymore in library projects. (The compile-time error I get is "The value for annotation attribute InjectView.value must be a constant expression"). For reference, this is my only Activity:

```
public class HelloAndroidActivity extends RoboSherlockActivity {

     @InjectView(R.id.helloworld) TextView textView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView.setText("Roboguice  says Hello World");
    }

}
```

IS there any proper way to create a base project with these three elements using maven and Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I accidentally clicked the "Is Library" checkbox on Project Properties. Now it works with ABS manually imported as a library.

It is a pity though not being able to use Maven directly :(

Comment: Does mvn work on the command line? We use these libs all the time with mvn cmd line builds, but haven't tried eclipse.